# Rolling a die with Chebyshev's inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, probability-distributions, dice

We roll a die $360$ times. We call an event a success when a face with even number of dots appears. Use Chebyshev's inequality to calculate interval in which the probability of having an obtained number of successes equals at least $0.9$.

My attempt:
$$Pr(|X-\mu|\geq t\sigma)\leq \frac{1}{t^2}$$
$$1-Pr(|X-\mu|\geq t\sigma)\geq1- \frac{1}{t^2}$$
$$Pr(|X-\mu|\leq t\sigma)\geq1- \frac{1}{t^2}$$
We have
$$1-\frac{1}{t^2}=0.9$$
$$\frac{1}{t^2}=0.1 \Rightarrow t=\sqrt{10}$$

The probability of obtaining an even numbered face in a single roll is
$$p=0.5$$
This is where I'm getting stuck. How do I calculate $\mu$ and $\sigma$?

Comment: $X$ is just a binomially distributed random variable, right? Do you know how to find the mean or variance of a binomial distribution?

Comment: $\mu=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\sigma^2=\frac{1}{4}$? But that's for a single roll, let's say $X_{i}$ and $X=X_{1}+...+X_{360}$. Are $\mu$ and $\sigma$ the same for $X$ or do I need to divide/multiply them by $360$?

Comment: Interesting! It's true that $X_i \sim B(1, \tfrac 12)$, giving these numbers. Have you ever seen something along the lines of $X \sim B(n, p)$? This is usually taught in probability courses, and often you can just quote that $\operatorname{Var}(X)=np(1 - p)$, $E[x] = np$. In this case $X \sim B(360, \tfrac 12)$.

Comment: We've used this kind of notation for normal distribution. Thank you for your help, you clarified a lot of things for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $μ=1/2$ and $σ^2=1/4$?

That´s right.

> But that's for a single roll, let's say $X_i$ and
> $X=X_1+...+X_{360}$. Are $μ$ and $σ$ the same for $X$ or do I need to
> divide/multiply them by 360?

The  expected value of the sum of the die rolls is equal to the sum of the extected values: $$\mathbb E\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{360} X_i \right)=360\cdot \mu_{x_1} $$

And  the variance  of the sum of the die rolls is equal to the sum of the variances, due independence of the rolls: $$Var\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{360} X_i  \right)=360\cdot \sigma^2_{x_1}$$